# Kakfa consumer.poll doesnt return record for 2.4.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am learning kafka and was following a tutorial for 2.0.0. I have a sample code for consumer

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    //Create consumer
   // KafkaConsumer<String,String>  kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);


    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

    // subscribe consumer to our topic(s)
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
    //Poll on new Data

    while(true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records =
                consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
            _log.debug("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
            _log.debug("Partition: " + record.partition() + ", Offset:" + record.offset());
        }
    }
```

This code worked with 2.0.0 but If i am updating the kafka version to 2.3.0 or 2.4.0 , records is coming as empty. 
I have already pushed messages to producer.

I have been going over the documents , but not able to figure out what needs to be changed here

Comment: Did you try resetting the consumer group or just changing the ID? What version of the broker is running?

Comment: I tried resetting the consumer group , even configured for a new topic. With 2.0.0 the code works , same code is returning 0 records for 2.4.0.
kafka-topics -version returns 2.4.0. I am guessing thats what the broker version should be

Comment: So I deleted the consumer group from command line
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --all-groups --delete 
and re-ran the code with group id as UUID, and it ran fine. 
I understand this might be an issue for an existing group due to offsets being not reset. However, any input on why it was not working for even new group ids?

Comment: Your code looks fine. There should be no difference in Kafka 2.0 and 2.4. It's not very clear how you're changing versions, though.

Comment: _Might be_ a side-effect of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8365 implemented in 2.3, although it should be backward compatible. Didn't have a chance to try it myself..